# Objective C - Core Data memory management?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, memory-management

1- Is these anything wrong with the way
   i am deallocing the object?

2- Does my dealloc override the dealloc
   for NSManagedObject?

3- Do i need to dealloc super even
   though my object is an
   NSManagedObject type and core data ia
   responsible for it?

```
@interface MyClass : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *coreDataString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *coreDataNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CoolObject *coolObject;

@end
```

.

```
@implementation MyClass
@dynamic coreDataString;
@dynamic coreDataNumber;
@synthesize coolObject;

- (void)dealloc
{
   [self.coolObject release];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, you are not calling `[super dealloc]`.
2. Yes.
3. Yes, you must always call `[super dealloc]` at the end of your dealloc method. Otherwise memory will not be freed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You should call release on the member variable directly instead of using the property. You also should still call the super dealloc. So your dealloc would look like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [coolObject release];
    coolObject = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Otherwise, you can set the property to nil which will automatically release the local variable if necessary. The above way is preferred so you don't accidentally run a complicated function that could be overriding the property's setter.

Comment: I was recently at a talk on the apple campus, and there they recommended doing `[coolObject release]; coolObject = nil;` instead of using the setter to set its value to nil.

Comment: oh interesting, did they say why? I actually do that myself most of the time but I thought I was going against their suggestion. Mostly because I like the consistency when I don't declare all variables as properties.

Comment: I just looked it up in the documentation and they do in fact say that you should call release on the local instance. The only reason to set it to nil is to prevent from accidentally having the same variable in the dealloc function more than once (calling release on the nil object won't do anything) so it is safer to do so. I will update the code above to be the preferred method.

Comment: the reason: a setter can run code that uses other objects. And if those used object where deallocated before you've invoked the setter your code will crash. In init and dealloc the object (self) can be in an invalid state. That's why you should not use setter in init or dealloc.

Answer (score 2):

You should always call [super dealloc] in the dealloc method. But in subclasses of NSManagedObject you should never use the dealloc method at all. use - (void)didTurnIntoFault instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the parents `- (void)dealloc` method. When you override a parent object's method, the parent's method is never called until you explicitly call the super's method. In your case, the parent's `- (void)dealloc` is not called. To fix this, you must call `[super dealloc]` to ensure that the parent's instance variables are deallocated too.